# How do I create a non-fullscreen App on the Meego tablet?

Tags: fullscreen, meego

I want to create an App for screen capturing on meego. But I found that an app must be fullscreen. I think my app is not fullscreen.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? Or another idea about screen capturing on meego?? BTW, my english is not good.